# PHP - Does an Include inside and IF will be included if the execution does not enter the IF?

Tags: php, include, if-statement

The question its self-explanatory. Example:

```
$x = 0;
if($x == 2)
{
include("stackoverflow.php");
}
```

Does the file **"stackoverflow.php"** will be included?

and a **Complementary Question**:
Look to this example:

```
//thispage.php contents
$x = $_GET['x'];
if($x == 2)
{
include("stackoverflow.php");
}
<a href="thispage.php?x=2">Click Here</a>
```

Lets suposse that the file **"thispage.php"** is sent to a lot of computers every second. does including the IF codes inside **"stackoverflow.php"** will make the file smaller to send to people if the IF has not been triggered?

Thankyou in advance

Comment: don't you just need to add like 2 more lines to just try the code you already wrote out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `stackoverflow.php` will not be included.

Actually, why didn't you just try it?

Comment: because i was in doubt if the PHP code, does only reads but not executes any of the include or if he isnt even includes de code

Comment: This is actually a fair question, because this behaviour was introduced to PHP in 4.1 IIRC. Before that, the includes actually got always parsed, independent from conditional blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The code is only `executed` on the web server, so it really depends if there's *content* in the include, or more code.

If the code executes and doesn't send anything to the client, then it wouldn't make anything *smaller* either way.

Comment: well that would make the code "Lighter" to the server process?